# ColdFusion json result from api call : how to address a field with a space in it's name?

Tags: json, coldfusion

I do an Airtable api call to create a record in our Airtable order table. The Airtable api result for creating the order looks like this :

```
{
    "id":"recj9wqdjnNzN3aiu",
    "fields": {
        "Branch":["rec5S0H7R87QtZ7qJ"],
        "Order no.":129,
        "Order line items":["recePdIxYgfYlKbaR"],
        "Name":"Order #129",
        "OrderPrice (excl VAT)":204.07,
        "RID":"recj9wqdjnNzN3aiu",
        "Product":["rec4j9TqDy8yJXFYg"]
    },
    "createdTime":"2022-03-03T13:20:22.000Z"
}
```

From this result I need the Order no.
To get the Name I can do :

```
<cfset filecontent = deserializeJSON(resultUpdAir.filecontent)>
<cfset orderid = filecontent.records[1].fields.name>
```

But how would I get the Order no. field since there is a space in it?

Comment: Try bracketnotation `<cfset orderid = filecontent.records[1]["fields"]["order no."]>`

Comment: <AustinPowers>Who provides an API that returns keys with spaces AND mixed case characters? I mean, honestly?</AustinPowers>

Comment: @AndreasRu You should post that as the answer.  It is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For situations like these the best way is to circumvent *dot.notation* and try  *bracket["notation"]* like this:

```
<cfset orderid = filecontent.records[1]["fields"]["order no."]>
```

Comment: Yes, perfect, thank you! I tried with brackets, but with the dot also in it, which obviously did not work.